# grep -f using -i option

Tags: logging, sed, awk, grep, qmail

I want to use grep with the -f, -i, and -v options.  I have a pattern file with the following contents:

vchkpw-pop3
vchkpw-submission
user_unknown
unknown_user
address_rejected
no_such_user
does_not_exist
invalid_recipient
mailbox_unavailable
user_not_found
no_mailbox_here

and I want to exclude all of the above terms when I am processing my qmail mail log files.

using Grep 2.5.1, it doesn't appear to work for any of the patterns starting from the 3rd position.

I am using a one line of bash code to parse my maillog file.  See the line below:

```
cat /var/log/maillog | tai64n2tai | awk '{$1="";$2="";$3="";$4="";$5="";print}'
| grep -v vchkpw-pop3 | grep -v vchkpw-submission | awk '{sub(/^[ \t]+/,"")};1'
| qlogselect start $STARTDAY end $ENDDAY | matchup > $QMAILSTATS 5>/dev/null
```

and instead of using multiple grep -v "sometext" in pipes, I wanted to use grep -vif patterns.txt in their place.

However, my problem is that in my version of grep, it won't allow me to use the f and i options together if the patterns contain an underscore(_) in them.  If I remove the underscore then the patterns match as expected.

Here is what an example line that I want to ommit  when parsing my maillog:

```
Sep 20 15:46:50 m qmail: 1348123610.323831 delivery 11150428: failure: 204.119.19.51_does_not_like_recipient./Remote_host_said:_550_5.1.1_User_unknown/Giving_up_on_204.119.19.51./
```

Since the error message is dependent upon the mail server I am contacting, sometimes the pattern user_unknown has capital letters and sometimes it doesn't.

Anyone have a better solution?

I like the idea of not having to edit the one line bash command everytime, and just add/remove a pattern from a file.

Comment: `grep -if patterns.txt file.txt` works for me. I have tested this using `GNU grep 2.6.3`. Are you absolutely sure you're having problems?

Comment: @steve thank you for your response.  I will attempt to upgrade Grep and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: It works in grep 2.5.1, but only for the first two patterns.  If I moved "user_unknown" into the 1st or 2nd position, it will find and exclude the lines.....else it will not.

Comment: I would suggest cleaning up your question and delete any unnecessary information including the example you have listed before your edit. I see you have added a pipeline to parse your maillog file. This is good. Most users will be familiar with a log file, but not the output of `tai64n2tai`. Therefore, I think it would be best to post a shortened version of the `tai64n2tai` output (or link to the whole output eg. dropbox). Example output is also highly desirable, please consider adding some. I think once you make the above changes, your question will be reopened.

Comment: My idea would be to use a single call to `awk` to replace: `| awk '{$1="";$2="";$3="";$4="";$5="";print}'
| grep -v vchkpw-pop3 | grep -v vchkpw-submission | awk '{sub(/^[ \t]+/,"")};1'`

Comment: @steve thanks again for your comments.  I will look into AWK.  yet I really like the idea of removing the patterns from the one line command and collecting them in the external file.  Can AWK do this?  I have not learned AWK yet btw.

Comment: Absolutely. I've got a working answer to your question. However, I'm waiting on 4 more votes to open your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`, assuming you have the patterns saved in a file called `patterns.txt`. This is the contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    IGNORECASE=1
}

FNR==NR {
    patterns[$0]++
    counter++
    next
}

{
    $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""
    sub(/^[ \t]+/,"")

    for (i in patterns) {
        if ($0 !~ i) {
            count++
        }
    }

    if (counter == count \
        && !/^$/) {
            print
    }

    count = 0
}
```

Run like this:

```
< /var/log/maillog | tai64n2tai | awk -f script.awk patterns.txt - | qlogselect start $STARTDAY end $ENDDAY | matchup > $QMAILSTATS 5>/dev/null
```

Alternatively, if you prefer not to use a script you will find this one liner useful:

```
< /var/log/maillog | tai64n2tai | awk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1 } FNR==NR { patterns[$0]++; counter++; next } { $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""; sub(/^[ \t]+/,""); for (i in patterns) { if ($0 !~ i) { count++ } } if (counter == count && !/^$/) { print } count = 0 }' patterns.txt - | qlogselect start $STARTDAY end $ENDDAY | matchup > $QMAILSTATS 5>/dev/null
```

Comment: I just verified that it works as expected.  Thank you very much!